# Popover won't hide after ajax call and not hovering action

Tags: jquery, ajax, popover

I have a popover and I'm adding the content attribute with an ajax call like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').hover(function() {
        var popover = $(this);
        popover.off('hover');
        getRemoteData(popover);
    });
});

function getRemoteData(popover) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/comentario/1',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            popover.attr('data-content', data).popover('show');
        }
    });
}
```

My problem is my popover is always triggered even if I'm not hovering, maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Also tried this method:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({title: "Header", content: function() { return //return ajax here;}, trigger: "hover"});
```

but instead of getting the ajax text I get [Object Object]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using hover event, you can use mouseenter and mouseleave events.

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on("mouseenter", function() {
    var e=$(this);  
    $.ajax({
        url: '/comentario/1',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            e.popover({content: data}).popover('show'); 
        }
    });
});

$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on("mouseleave", function() {
    var e=$(this);
    $(this).popover('hide'); 
});
```

It will behave like hover and work fine.

Comment: works fine if i change e.popover({content: data}).popover('show');  for e.attr('data-content', data).popover('show');